# Eclipse RCP - How to use Annotation to show error in text editor

Tags: java, annotations, eclipse-rcp

Annotations are used to show errors on text editors.
Once AnnoationTypes extension are added as shown below. Could you please tell me what needs to be done to bind the Annotation to the text editor.

```
<extension
         point="org.eclipse.ui.editors.annotationTypes">
      <type
            markerSeverity="2"
            name="com.fd.vplus.prac.editor.Error"
            super="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.error">
      </type>
      <type
            markerSeverity="1"
            name="com.fd.vplus.prac.editor.Warning"
            super="org.eclipse.ui.workbench.texteditor.warning">
      </type>
   </extension>
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: We have seen compilation error as red underline in eclipse java editors. Similar thing I want to achived.

Comment: This tutorial article might help.https://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Mark%20My%20Words/mark-my-words.html